# Import npm module using es6 style imports without transpiling?

Tags: npm, import, ecmascript-6, module

I would like to call an npm module from my code which is an es6 module.  Is there a way to do this without transpiling or bundling my code?  The reason I don't want to transpile is for simplicity and so I can see my code changes instantly in the browser when I'm debugging.

Comment: Ok, I didn't get a solution, so I perused the code and found a hack that works:The nmp module I am using is html2canvas. At the top of the bundled webpack file I added `export let html2canvas={};`  In the webpackUniversalModuleDefinition function I changed `root["html2canvas"] = factory();`  to `html2canvas = factory();`  and then I could import html2canvas into my es6 module.   `import  {html2canvas} from './node_modules/html2canvas/dist/html2canvas.js';`

Comment: [Snowpack](https://www.snowpack.dev/concepts/how-snowpack-works) seems close to what you want, but not an exact match.

Answer (score 1):

You can work with native ESM modules in the browser using the `script type="module"`. It works only [for browsers that support it](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module).

`index.html`

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
      <script type="module" src="my-script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`my-script.js`

```
import {stuff} from './module1.js';
import Stuff from './module2.js';

console.log(Stuff);
console.log(stuff);
```

`module1.js`

```
export const stuff = {b: 1};
```

`module2.js`

```
export default {a: 1};
```

Then setup a quick web server to see the page working:

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer 7654`

That said, if your problem is refreshing your code at every change and debug it in ES6 dev mode, I recommend `sourceMaps` as the solution. With `sourceMaps` you can see your code working compiled (or "transpiled" as you like) as in production while debugging the development version in ES6. Webpack (or alternatives) is very optimized right now and can do partial compiling [very quickly](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/) reloading the browser at every save.

Comment: True, however what I am asking is how to import **npm** modules into my javascript es6 module, which is more difficult since npms use the commonjs style modules.